# How can i Built Qt-Creator against Qt5, in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: qt

I had an existing Qt4 installation on my ubuntu built using the "Software center". After that, I installed Qt5 from git using the default settings. Now, realizing that the Qt Creator version I had, was configured for Qt 4.8.1, I uninstalled it (using software center) and now i am looking for some guidance to re-build it and link against Qt5. From their blog, I have noticed that the latest version should be a part of Qt5 installation but I am unable to start it from the HUD in ubuntu, nor do i know of any command-line options to fire it up from the terminal. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have builded Qt2,Qt4.6 and Qt4.8.The procedure of building Qt is almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

Hate to just throw up a link, but this guy explains it well.. for multiple operating systems.

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the [Qt wiki](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git).

An example procedure of build:

> ./configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests
>
> ./make
>
> ./make install

Your build target may be ARM or other platform,then you can use `./configure --help` to see more configure help.